# Alfresco NTLM Authentication fails

Tags: windows, authentication, curl, alfresco, ntlm

There is a problem querying Alfresco `CMIS` using `NTLM` authentication: Authentication is fails on third handshake.

```
*   Trying 192.168.1.1...
* Connected to ecm.corp.knastu.ru (192.168.1.1) port 8080 (#0)
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'alf_user'
> GET /alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/ HTTP/1.1

> Host: 192.168.1.1:8080
> Authorization: NTLM TlUAAB........AAAAKANcDw==
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> 

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=CEED8E135E6D57BCF8A99A027C08EB; Path=/alfresco/; HttpOnly
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM TRTHgAAAA+AD4AkAA........vJfTeuwAAAACAAYAZQBjA0AAAAAAAAAAA=
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2017 07:25:16 GMT
< 


> GET /alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/browser/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: 192.168.1.1:8080
> Authorization: NTLM TRTHgAAAA+AD4AkAA........vJfTeuwAAAACAAYAZQBjA0AAAAAAAAAAA=
> User-Agent: curl/7.46.0
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: JSESSIONID=CEED8E135E6D57BCF8A99A027C08EB
> 

< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
* NTLM handshake rejected
* Authentication problem. Ignoring this.
< WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 238
< Date: Mon, 20 Nov 2017 07:25:16 GMT
< 

* Connection #0 to host 192.168.1.1 left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Alfresco Content Services supports NTLM v2 protocol, which is more
>   secure than NTLM v1 protocol. However, NTLM v2 cannot be used with
>   pass-through authentication. You will have to switch to NTLM v1 if you
>   want to use pass-through authentication, where the log on request is
>   passed to an Active Directory or other server to validate the login
>   credentials.
>
> [Source](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/troubleshoot-ntlm.html)

To authenticate using NTLM v1, set the following registry key on your client machines:

```
[HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa] "LmCompatibilityLevel"=dword:00000001
```

> This problem is most likely caused by enhanced security in Windows 7,
>   Vista and Windows 2008. Previous versions of Windows (XP) would fall
>   back to NTLM v1, if NTLM v2 failed.
>
> 1. On Windows 7 clients, navigate to Control Panel > Administrative
>      Tools > Local Security Policy.
> 2. In the left pane, navigate to Security Settings > Local Policies > Security Options.
> 3. In the right pane, find Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level.
> 4. By default, the value of Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level is set to Send NTLMv2 response only. Refuse LM
>      & NTLM.
> 5. Set the value of Network Security: LAN Manager authentication level to Send LM and NTLM - use NTLMv2 session security if
>      negotiated.
>
> This setting allows Windows 7 to use the more secure NTLM v2, if
>   available, and fall back to NTLM v1 for Alfresco Content Services. If
>   the machines are in a domain, it is possible to change this setting on
>   all of them by using the group policy editor on the domain controller.
>
> [Source](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/tasks/troubleshoot-ntlm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see you're giving the user, but without any domain :

```
* Server auth using NTLM with user 'alf_user'
```

So, try again when adding the domain, such as :

```
curl -v -u mydomain/alf_user:mypassword ...
```

Comment: Whole infrastructure placed under single domain, so, domain name is not necessary here.

Comment: How does your curl command knows that everything is on the same domain ? You're sending a curl output, and I'm answering to it. Logical.

Comment: I tried put domain name in credentials, the result is the same. In Alfresco's preferences there is only one domain, so Alfresco searches in that in any case.